# No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'android' / new pacakge

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I've been trying to work out what's wrong with code but, I'am clueless now, pretty much checked everything, i get this error when am trying to build the login page for my app. Sorry for any inconvenience, i'am pretty noob at this.

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'android'. (line 2)

As well as a different error from java to deploy the theme for the app:

> [image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@color/uberPrimary"
        >

        <Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImageView1"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/centerimage" 
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/circleImageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@color/uberwhite"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/emailText"
        >
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_widht="match_parent"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        >
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_widht="match_parent"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"

            />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/uberwhite"
            android:background="@drawable/uberroundbutton"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

        </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your edittexts you have typos with `android:layout_widht`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
    <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_widht="match_parent"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        />
```

to

```
   <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        />
```

credit to @laalto